# IIS Server Express Fails on DB

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I have a strange issue which is getting worse as I add more code to my site.... Sometimes after I edit code IIS express will refuse to function correctly. I.E. my login function takes way longer than usual and I'm not logged in. Any calls to DB for that matter fail. I've been shutting down Visual Studio and restarting, this seems to fix the issue in most cases, but is there a better way? I've tried stopping debugging and rebuilding the site but that doesn't seem to help.

I've just added some Console.WriteLine statements to the catch on the db call which pulls user data from the DB on login but I'm not getting anything there. How do I get IIS Express to update what it's running without restarting visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by mis-configuration of ISS EXPRESS. Installation and re-installation did not fix the problem, but deleting the ISS EXPRESS directory from my user's profile did.

I had over 50 sites configured throughout my classes in UNI which I believe were causing the problem.